# RadioButton is not checked when changed

Tags: extjs, extjs5

i am working on creating a radiogroup containing two radios;
I set a change listener on the radiogroup and everything seems to be working fine except that visually the radio buttons are not checked when clicked on, see below full code :

```
Ext.define('Mine.view.headerThemeButton', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.headerThemeButton',
    xtype: 'headerThemeButton',
    width: 50,
    height: 58,
    padding: 'auto 0 auto 0',
    bodyStyle: 'border-color: #FFFFFF !important;',
    //id : 'headerThemeButton',
    //height: 20,
    items: [{
        xtype: 'button',
        height: '100%',
         glyph: 'xf142@FontAwesome',
  
        cls: 'headerButtonsCls',
        listeners: {
            click: function(e, target) {
            
                var coords = e.getXY();
                var x = parseInt(coords[0]);
                var y = parseInt(coords[1]);

                 var finalY = y + 50;
                Ext.create('Ext.menu.Menu', {
                    items: [{
                        xtype: 'radiogroup',
                        columns: 1,
                        vertical: true,
                        items: [{
                            //xtype: 'radiofield',
                            boxLabel: 'Dark Mode',
                            name  : 'Mode',
                            //id : 'dmRB',
                            inputValue : 'dm'

                         }, {
                            //xtype: 'radiofield',
                            boxLabel: 'Standard Mode',
                            name  : 'Mode',
                            //id : 'smRB',
                            inputValue : 'sm'

                         }],
                        listeners : {

                             change : function(radio, newValue, oldValue){
                          
                                if (radio.getValue().Mode == 'dm'){

                                    radio.checked = true;
                                     this.onChangeThemeDark();
                                    }
                                else if (radio.getValue().Mode == 'sm'){
                                     radio.checked = true;
 
                                    this.onChangeThemeStandard();
                                    }
                            }
                        }
                    }]
                }).showAt(x, finalY);
            }

        }
    }]
});
```

I can't use id prop on each radio because that will raise a duplicate registration error.
Any solution ?

Thanks !

EDIT  : the whole button is included in a interface defined by :

```
Ext.define('Mine.view.newDashboard', {
    extend: 'Ext.container.Viewport',
    alias: 'widget.newDashboard',

    controller: 'newDashboard',
    reference: 'dashboard',
    //overflowY: 'scroll',

    //autoScroll:true,
    layout: {
        type: 'border',
        align: 'stretch '
        //scrollable: true
    },
    /*viewConfig:
    {
        autoScroll: true
    },*/
    //height: 620,

    style: {
        'backgroundColor': '#909090 !important'
    },

    items: [{
            region: 'north',
            html: '',
            border: false,
            collapsible: false,
            margin: '0 0 0 0',
            resizable: false,
            //bodyStyle:'border-bottom-width: 0 !important;',
            layout: {
                type: 'hbox'

                // align: 'stretch'
            },
            items: [{
                    xtype: 'logolink',
                    padding: 'auto 0 auto 0'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'tbfill'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'headerThemeButton',
                    width: '100px'
                },...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure exactly what you are asking but I assume it is the problem that when the menu comes up after selecting a value nothing is selected.  Also maybe that you can't get each button in the event.

Here is a fiddle that shows how to get each button in the event, two different ways.

Also each time you clicked the button you were creating a new menu so you were showing a new set of radio buttons each time the button was clicked.  I am creating a menu on the button then showing it when clicked.

You could also create a menu and store it on the panel (or anywhere) and show that menu each time if you did not want it attached to the button.

[Fiddle radio buttons](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3abu)

Comment: For the `this.onChangeThemeStandard();` to work the method should be defined in the controller of the whole interface right ?

Comment: if you were to call that in the event handler the method would have to be on the scope of "this"  The scope of this is the radiogroup.   in the case of the fiddle "this" is the same as the variable radio  so you could call this.themeChange or radio.themeChange.    I created a method and I am calling in the fiddle, go change it out.  Please include the version of extjs you are using and also the toolkit, so Extjs 7.3.1 Modern   or 6.0 classic.

Comment: It's ExtJS 6.2.0

Comment: Also... you could create a controller and put the method in the controller.   You could add a method to the controller.  Then you could set the controller to watch for events, then fire the event that runs the method..... this is good for model view controller.  Then you don't have any logic in your view...

Comment: No, `Mine.view.headerThemeButton` is included in a container using the syntax `{xtype : headerThemeButton}`, that main container is binded to a controller. Now what i want is to define the `onChangeThemeDark()` method in that controller, and my question would be how to call it from within the listener of the radiofield ? Thanks !

Comment: Please see edit for the main container ( where the theme button is included) code (which is binded to a controller )

Comment: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3ac2   In your controller you have to tell the system to control radio group.  then you name the event and what method to call.  Then you fire the event in the radiogroup click event.   The controller on the panel is fireing the event but any controller UP from the button group can watch for the event.    If you wanted to call the method directly and not fire an event you would have to get the controller from the component can call the event.

Comment: To call directly did you mean smth like `let panel = radio.up('headerThemeButton').up('newDashboard'); `? because the button is inside the main interface as mentioned

Comment: YES it worked with the help of your direct way method and using the double up syntax i just mentioned so thanks so much !

Comment: Just curious for the second method if you fire an event on change how to catch it and where ?

Comment: Check out the second fiddle it explains how to control for the event in your controller. You sat control then the  selector for the component that will fire the event. I am in my phone. I will make it more clear in the fiddle when I get home

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224937/discussion-between-mcg1103-and-ites).

Comment: sure ! i'm in !